# I'm curious about the difference between the "deleteIn~" method and the "deleteIn~Batch" method

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

As far as I know, the difference between the two methods is that DB has or does not have the "In" keyword in its deletion query. However, when the "Batch" keyword was attached, it was confirmed that the function provided by the persistence context was not used.

Is there a particular reason why data jpa works this way? If not, I think it would be better in terms of performance for the Batch keyword to go through the persistence context as well.